# Angular 4 template with context not working

Tags: angular, templates

I'm working on a dynamic form component I have created and the custom templates I'm using are unable to get the context correctly.

Here is my ng-template:

```
  <ng-template #defaultTemplate let-field>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="!field.isValid() ? 'has-error' : ''">
      <label class="control-label" [for]="field.property">{{ field.label }}</label>
      <app-dynamic-form-field [formField]="field"></app-dynamic-form-field>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

And here is how I use it:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of formModel.formFields">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="fieldTemplate || defaultTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="getContextForTemplate(field)">

    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Here is the typescript of the component related to create the context:

```
  getContextForTemplate(field: BaseFormField<any>) {
    return {
      $implict: field
    };
  }
```

The error I'm having is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined

Though the form field object does have the isValid method. If I don't use the code above as template and directly inside the *ngFor of the container everything works as it should.

Edit:
I have tried this code as well and it does not seem to work:

```
<form>
  <ng-template #defaultTemplate let-field>
    <div>
      {{ field }}
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of [1,2,3]" [ngTemplateOutlet]="defaultTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{ $implict: 'hello' }">

  </ng-container>

  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

Comment: how does the field property get populated in your component?  It looks like it's just undefined when you call .isValid() on it.

Comment: It is defined, the fields are populated before and working if it's not used as a template.

Comment: Can you provide reproduction?

Comment: There is a lot of code running in the background, but I can see that the getContextForTemplate is called with the field populated correctly. It just seems that the ng-template doesn't get a hold of it correctly.

Comment: I do not need all your code. I am just asking for minimal reproduction

Comment: I have added a sample code to reproduce in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit idiotic but the problem was a typo, this:

```
  getContextForTemplate(field: BaseFormField<any>) {
    return {
      $implict: field
    };
  }
```

should be changed into:

```
  getContextForTemplate(field: BaseFormField<any>) {
    return {
      $implicit: field
    };
  }
```

Or in other words: $implict should be $implicit instead.